# DateTime problem when day <= 12

Tags: c#, datetime

I've looked around a lot and short of writing a horrible chunk of code to manipulate the string, I'd like to ask if anyone knows a nice way of sorting it:

I have a bunch of date strings in cells that I'm pulling out such as:

03/05/2011
27/05/2011
31/05/2011
03/05/2011
09/05/2011
31/05/2011
etc.

While I'm reading any entires where the day can be construed as a month - i.e. entries 1, 4 and 5 above - it gets put in as a DateTime with the day and month swapped.

For example, 03/05/2011 gets read in as a DateTime "05/03/2011 00:00:00"
The others are all read and nicely provide me with a simple string of "27/05/2011".

I'm getting this info from Excel, using

```
((Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[rowCount, 3]).Value.ToString()
```

If I try Value2 as with my other lines, it reads those odd dates as things like "40607" but again, will read the other dates normally.

Comment: What culture/locale are you using?

Comment: @Skurmedel: en-GB (my requirement of the dates such as 27/05/2011 should give that away) but it doesn't quite seem to be a localization issue. It's got an odd behaviour when reading only those dates where it could be ambiguous as to which way around the days and months are. All the other entires are read perfectly.

Answer (score 8):

If you use the [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) function to convert a string to a `DateTime` object, you can specify the specific format used by your dates (which looks like "day/month/year") without having to do any string manipulation whatsoever.

Example:

```
var dateString = "03/05/2011";

var format = "dd/MM/yyyy";

var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

More information on custom Date and Time format strings can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

---

**EDIT:** Try using the [`DateTime.FromOADate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate.aspx) method to convert the value returned by the [`Range.Value2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.value2.aspx) property to a `DateTime` object, e.g. something like this:

```
var dateTime = DateTime.FromOADate(((Excel.Range)worksheet.Cells[rowCount, 3]).Value2);
```

Comment: I've tried such things. My problem seems to be that immediately upon reading the value in the cell, it's reading it as a DateTime in an incorrect format before I've even asked it to.

However, why won't it read the rest of the entries as DateTimes? Will it really scrutanize them over the CultureInfo upon reading the cells?

Comment: @Aidan Then it should work, ParseExact was created for exactly your situation.

Comment: @Scott: I still get "05/03/2011 00:00:00" out of my cell instead of "03/05/2011" that I should be getting and get with the rest of my cells (using ParseExact errors when it encounters the first normal entry).

Comment: What are you entering for the second field of ParseExact?

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain Good catch; added `/` to the format string.

Comment: @Aidan - Scott correctly noted that I needed to add slashes to the format string. I've updated my answer; does using this format still cause an error to be thrown when `DateTime.ParseExact` is used?

Comment: @Donut: I picked up on that before and no, it doesn't solve the issue.
@Scott: I've added Convert.ToDateTime before extracting my cell data and so far it's made it nicer in that all my entries are now of DateTime which is fine, but I'm still getting those odd dates coming out the same.

Comment: @Aidan On second thought, you may be able to solve this using the `DateTime.FromOADate` method. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Donut: Value2 doesn't work properly with all my cells. It works on the odd cells but, again, it's coming out 05/03/2011 then when it hits the next entry it throws up. For some reason it's seeing those two dates as different types of entries.

Comment: Don't use `.Value.ToText()`. Use `.Text`. See my answer for details.

Comment: @BradC: I am using .Text. It's still not happy with me. If I set the cells' .NumberFormat = "@" then it sets my odd entries into 40607 style. I suppose I can cut my losses here and shove an if in there to check and see what's come out of that cell and process it appropriately.

Comment: Even DateTime.FromOADate 'ing the 40607 style number comes out as 05/03/2011 instead of the expected 03/05/2011, even when telling it to use en-GB locale. Funnily enough, changing it to en-US doesn't alter my existing 'correct' entries at all.

Answer (score 2):

[DateTime.ParseExact Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ee1y0t7.aspx) converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its DateTime equivalent using the specified format and culture-specific format information.

The format of the string representation must match the specified format exactly.

```
String dateString = "15/06/2008";
String format = "dd/MM/yyyy";

DateTime result = 
   DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a localization problem. Try setting your locale implicititly. For example in WPF application it's something like:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 
    new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
```

Comment: Setting the Thread to my locale doesn't do the trick either. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a bunch of date strings in cells that I'm pulling out such as:

No, you don't. You have a mix of **strings that look like dates** and **dates that look like strings**. This is an Excel issue, not a C# issue.

Not sure if you are creating the spreadsheet, or if you are getting it from somewhere else. But it the problem is that Excel attempt to parse text *as it is entered in the cell*. In this case, it is making some wrong decisions about the dates it finds.

If you enter a date like "03/05/2011", Excel will (incorrectly) parse it as March 5th, 2011, and store that as a numeric date code (40607). It then applies a *date formatting* to the cell (it uses m/d/yyyy on my machine).

If you enter a date like "31/05/2011", Excel can't parse it as a date, and it stores it as text.

To prove this, select the cells and go to Edit > Clear > Formats. All the "bad dates" will just show as numbers, all the rest will stay looking like dates.

You have a few choices:

1. Fix the data before its entered into Excel (prepend everything with a ' so its all entered as text, or make sure to create the spreadsheet on a machine that has the right date settings.)
2. Don't use the `.Value.ToString()` from Excel, just use `.Text`. This will ignore the bad parsing that Excel did, and should give you a consistent text value (from both types) that you can `ParseExact` with C#, per the other answers.

(2) is a lot easier, and if the spreadsheets already exist, may be your only choice.

Comment: Yup, I thought of that as well as I was searching through other people with similar problems. Using .Text returns me "########" instead of what's entered. I figured it had to be something odd that Excel was doing, but for the life of me I can't seem to get round it. All the cells are already formatted and set to the correct locale, but yes, setting them to text will show 40607 style entries. I'd rather not have to alter the cell format before reading but it's starting to look like won't have a choice...

Comment: `.Text` literally returns what's shown in the spreadsheet itself (after all formatting is applied, etc.) So the only way it would return "######" is if the column isn't wide enough to show the date format. Does it literally show "#####" in the spreadsheet itself? Can you widen the column so it doesn't?

Comment: And altering the cell format isn't going to fix the problem. Excel has literally parsed the dates wrong, it swapped the month and day values. You can verify this by changing to a "June 22, 2011" style format.

Comment: Nope, in the file, no matter what format I change the cell to, it consistently displays the correct date - 03/05/2011, 03 May 2011, 03-05-11, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because your Dates are being read as american culture or similar.

If you use the following you can specify the format you expect your dates to be in:use

```
DateTime result;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact("dd/MM/yyyy", out result))
{
   // Got an English date
 }
```