# Wrong date being returned to controller from view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I have a custom datepicker which enables the user to select date from a drop drown and displays it in a textbox in the view. The format used here is 'mm/dd/yy'.

When user submits a request, I am passing this to the controller through an AJAX post. Here the values are being taken from textboxes 
`txtStartTime` and `txtEndTime`.  [For ex: if user selects November 1,2016 it is displayed as `11/01/16`]

```
function SubmitData() { 
    var obj = { TaskId: ccount, TrajName: $('#drpTraj').find(":selected").text(), StartTime: $('#txtStartTime').val(), EndTime: $('#txtEndTime').val(), Aggr: $('#drpAggr').find(":selected").text() }

    var jobvm = {}
    jobvm["data"] = obj;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Data/SubmitData",
        data: JSON.stringify({ dataObj: jobvm }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        success: function (msg) {
            ServiceSucceeded(msg);
        },
        error: function () {
            return "error";
        }
    });
}
```

The data class code :

```
public int TaskId { get; set; }
public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
public string Aggr { get; set; }
public string TrajName { get; set;}
```

My issue is that when I select a date like `November 1,2016`, it is displayed in the view and passed as `11/01/16`. But once it reaches the controller,
the date is displayed as `11 Jan 2016`  instead of `01 Nov 2016`.

I tried the solution suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6441352/5621607]) like below code :

```
var dateString = dataObj.StartTime;
var format = "MM/dd/yyyy";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But it is not returning the date correctly, as the data received in the controller is already 11 January 2016. 
Even I tried `dataObj.StartTime.ToString("MM-dd-yy")`. But everything is returning 11 January only.
Please help me to find a solution for this.

Comment: That means the culture on your server is one that accepts dates in `dd/MM/yyyy` - either change the culture, or use a custom ModelBinder

Comment: I would suggest to set the date using current culture, or by setting the desired culture on current thread. by this way you won't have to convert date formats.

Comment: @StephenMuecke : I am already receiving as `11 January 2016`. So if I change the culture will it become `01 November 2016`? May I know what is modelbinder?

Comment: @DirtyDeveloper :  Did you mean to change the culture at this point `var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` ?

Comment: I don't think that will work. try to set in on the page load for the datetime textboxes. Just to try! and convert it to whatever format you require before saving to DB

Comment: @ViVi, Using `DateTime.ParseExact()` in your controller is too late - the `DefaultModelBinder` has already bound the value. Change the culture in the `web.config` file

Comment: Refer [this article](https://blog.greatrexpectations.com/2013/01/10/custom-date-formats-and-the-mvc-model-binder/) for an example of a custom DateTime ModelBinder

Comment: @StephenMuecke : I think it should fix the issue. I have just checked the same scenario in my test server at Europe. This issue is not there in test server. Maybe because I am using `en-US` and it is something else.

Comment: How about sending the date from the client-side in ISO format to avoid the server guessing the date format?

Answer (score 0):

How about sending the date from the client-side in ISO format to avoid the server guessing the date format?

```
var startTimeInClientCulture = '11/01/16'; //$('#txtStartTime').val();
var startTimeInIso = new Date(startTimeInClientCulture);
startTimeInIso.setTime( startTimeInIso.getTime() - startTimeInIso.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000 );
//use startTimeInIso.toISOString() if you need a string instead of a Date type
//and send this in the ajax call
```

Comment: Sorry. But I didn't get you. Did you mean sending it as `01/11/16` from client side to get `November 1st 2016`?

Comment: With the JavaScript code above, the value `'11/01/16'` will be converted to the format `2016-11-01T00:00:00.000Z`. And if you send this value in the ajax request, the server will be able to create a `DateTime` instance of `Nov 1, 2016` instead of `11 Jan, 2016`.

Comment: @ViVi, did you try this?